# Design of combined ListItems is broken by divider in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to connect my different list items on the left side as you can see in the picture.

[image]

The problem is that the divider breaks them and there are little gaps between in the line. Is there a solution for this? I have already thought about setting the divider to 0dp and integrating a line on the bottom side of each list item, but I think this is not the optimal solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO, switch from `ListView` to `RecyclerView`. It is newer, more flexible, and does not come with default dividers.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I think I'll look at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `LinearLayout` at bottom of layout with `android:layout_height="2dp` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and remove the divider. This way the space occupied by divider would be gone.

Comment: Thanks, I have already thought about something similiar and think I'll do as you said.

Comment: @Rotwang yeah we can add view as well but I was not going to use it to cover the gap so not left side but as a replacement to divider

Comment: Oh. I see. My bad. +1